# Shorten urls adds some chars end of url and it causes 404 error on wordpress site

Tags: wordpress, http-status-code-404, iis-7.5

Our Wordpress site is hosted on IIS 7.5 server and while we share a post link on Linkedin (eg. http://sitename.com/postname/), its shorten the link as expected but when you click the link its give 404 error. The url from linkedin is http://sitename.com/postname/%C2%A0

The problem seems that "%C2%A0" addition.

Any idea to fix that problem? I have refreshed the permalinks but did not help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When i face the similar issue i first tried Permanent 301 Redirect in .htaccess , it fixed my problem , 
or consider this plugin : [301 redirect](https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/)

> i suggest instead of using the htaccess file, you should download a
>   wordpress plugin called SImple 301 Redirects. It's very easy. Maybe if
>   you do the 301 reidrects at the wordpress plugin level then wordpress
>   can handle them better. [source](https://moz.com/community/q/htaccess-redirect-with-c2-a0-in-url/#reply_3085)

EIDT
on IIS try this

> ```
> <!-- Web.config file in subdirectory to be redirected -->
> <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
> <configuration>
>   <system.webServer>
>     <rewrite>
>       <rules>
>         <rule name="RedirectRule" stopProcessing="true">
>           <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true" />
>           <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.newdomain.com/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
>             <conditions>
>                 <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www\.old-domain\.com" />
>             </conditions>
>         </rule>
>       </rules>
>     </rewrite>
>   </system.webServer>
> </configuration>
> ```
>
> If using WordPress (or other web application that can rewrite local
>   files), make sure the Web.config file isn’t writeable. [source](https://www.make-awesome.com/2010/03/301-redirects-with-iis7-rewrite-module/)

Comment: I have tried 301 redirect but its not saving "%C2%A0" so its not working. Because of IIS 7.5? And its not only a url, all links when we share on linkedin it adds that %C2%A0 chars so very hard to define all urls